# Does this procedure takes too much RAM while creating + scaling a Bitmap?

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I have an "init" procedure that fill the contents of a array of Bitmaps (a "cache"), reading pixels from a single, big, int array. 
Before saving each one of them, images could need to be resized to a "target" dimension. So I have to first create the full size Bitmap with `Bitmap.createBitmap`, then save it in the cache using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`.

Obviously I don't want to fill up the memory, but it happens "sometimes" during the procedure. What I'm missing? I'm wondering if the first Bitmap created with `Bitmap.createBitmap` is actually deleted just after the `setImageCache` function, or not.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    setImageCache(i, Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            Bitmap.createBitmap(intArray, area * i, origW, origW, origH, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888), 
            targetW, targetH, true
    ));
}
```

Comment: please refer to this [page](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) from the android developer team.

Comment: I've read it and I used in another part of my application. The problem, here, is that my input is an int array. BitmapFactory.decode* functions don't take such kind of data type to decode a Bitmap :(

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't get OutOfMemoryExceptions everything should be fine, but you can improve your code by recycling not needed bitmaps like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(intArray, area * i, origW, origW, origH, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, targetW, targetH, true);
    bitmap.recycle();
    setImageCache(i, scaledBitmap);
}
```

By recycling bitmaps you don't need you release the memory taken up by those not needed bitmaps and that can significantly curb memory problems when dealing with large images.

Comment: Are you sure it is relevant for this particular case? Just tried and nothing changes (means "random OutOfMemory while repeating that procedure").

Comment: Well it is definitely an improvement, probably not much because the scaled images take up the bulk of the memory. If that doesn't provide the improvement you are looking for than your are going to have to rethink how and when you load images. My next suggestion would be using disk and memory caches, I can help you with implementing something like this if you want, but it all depends on your requirements.

Comment: The first question you should ask yourself is, do you really need all those bitmaps in your memory at the same time?

Comment: Surely no, I "just" need the resized version of each Bitmap.
(and, yes, they all will be displayed at the same time)

Comment: And I assume you already scale each image to the size of the container it is going to be displayed in?

Comment: Well then it's going to difficult to fix that. If you could post more of your code, how you display those bitmaps etc I can take a look at it and maybe suggest further improvements.